# Synchronize multiple celery queues

Tags: python, celery

My on-prem system has a limited capacity (memory) and scale-out is not possible.
The system runs a celery task for every message. There are 2 types of tasks: "light" and "heavy". The memory consumption of every task type is known. Let's say, the memory consumption of a heavy task is 10x of memory consumption of a light task. The system can run concurrently up to 5 heavy tasks or up to 50 light tasks or any other combination, for example 2 heavy tasks and 30 light tasks.

How can I build a system that runs optimal number of tasks, subject to the capacity constraint?
If I put tasks to separate queues - is there any mechanism that allows to synchronization / coordination between queues or / and workers?

The system latency is critical. Any additional intermediate queue affects the latency painfully.

Comment: Additional challenge is to prevent a starvation for heavy tasks. If heavy tasks queue length is longer than a given threshold - do not start light tasks at all to allow enough resources to run a heavy task.

Comment: That's a knapsack problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem